# How to require.ensure a chunk from memory-fs in webpack?

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

Let's say I have a webpack configuration uses memory-fs as outputFileSystem and the target is node. And somewhere in the code I use require.ensure to split the code. In this case, when I try to require the module it tries to find the module in the disk and throws a "module not found error". What I want is, require to load split module from memory-fs as well. I couldn't find any appropriate loader or plugin fits this case. So, I will create my own. But I couldn't decide if I need a webpack plugin or a loader?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm trying to use webpack-hot-server-middleware with code splitting and hitting this issue.

Comment: For now, I've left chunking on but when it comes to rendering on the server I only match against "/". My app is rendered serverside with this url, sent to the client and the client picks up whatever URL you requested and re-renders at correct URL. This is fine for development, on production of course all the bundles are available on disk and the problem goes away.