# webpack replace require cache from memory-fs

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm using expressjs for api server, I want to replace require.cache by webpack memory fs compiler output on server runtime to achieve hot reload.
What I know is if I compile to hard drive disk, I could easily delete require cache to hot reload.

And, the same question as [How to require.ensure a chunk from memory-fs in webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506990/how-to-require-ensure-a-chunk-from-memory-fs-in-webpack)

this introduce another problem. can we start a process from memory-fs and let that process access memory-fs instead of HDD?